# Integrating product of Probability Density Functions with Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

```
from scipy import stats
import scipy.integrate as integrate

y1 = 90; n1 = 100; y2 = 2; n2 = 2;

result1 = integrate.dblquad(lambda theta1, theta2: (stats.beta.pdf(theta1, y1+1, n1-y1+1)*stats.beta.pdf(theta2,y2+1, n2-y2+1)*(theta1>theta2)),0,1, lambda x: 0, lambda x:1)

result2=integrate.quad(lambda theta1: (stats.beta.pdf(theta1, y1+1, n1-y1+1)*stats.beta.cdf(theta1,y2+1, n2-y2+1)),0,1)
```

Gives:

```
>>result1 
1.916...
>>result2
0.71..
```

Why do these differ? Unless I am missing something, the value of the cumulative density function up to an arbitary point is the same as the integral of the pdf up to that point, so `stats.beta.pdf(theta2,y2+1, n2-y2+1)*(theta1>theta2)` should give the cdf up to that point, for example:

```
>>print integrate.quad(lambda theta2: stats.beta.pdf(theta2,y2+1, n2-y2+1)*(theta2<0.9),0,1)
(0.7290000000000001, 8.093525849517392e-15)
>>print stats.beta.cdf(0.9,y2+1, n2-y2+1)

0.729
```

The first term is clearly the same, so why the (large) discrepancy?

This code is from an example from Kevin Murphys excellent book, and the accompanying matlab code is here: 
https://github.com/probml/pmtk3/blob/master/demos/amazonSellerDemo.m

His book states 0.71 as the answer, yet he computes it using the first method. I don't have matlab, so cannot confirm that it is not an error in the book and his code, but it's not obvious why it would be incorrect.

Method 2 comes from the analytic solution on the first page here: 
http://www.johndcook.com/UTMDABTR-005-05.pdf

Edit:

And to add, the following implementation of the trapezium rule gives the correct (analytic) answer.

```
func = lambda theta1: integrate.quad(lambda theta2: stats.beta.pdf(theta2,y2+1, n2-y2+1)*(theta2<theta1),0,1)[0]*stats.beta.pdf(theta1,91,11)

step = 0.001
area=0
for x in np.arange(0,1,step):
    if((x==0)|(x==1-step)):
        area += func(x)
    else:
        area += 2*func(x)

area *= step/2
print area

0.7125...
```

Comment: When I run your code using scipy version 0.17.0, I get `result1 = (0.7125919475596585, 6.966216639647053e-07)`.

Comment: What do you get when you run `integrate.dblquad(lambda theta1, theta2: (beta.pdf(theta1, y1+1, n1-y1+1)*beta.pdf(theta2, y2+1, n2-y2+1)), 0, 1, lambda x: x, lambda x: 1)`? This is like method1 except that it takes advantage of the `gfun`/`hfun` parameters to shape the domain. For me this returns `(0.7125928041119365, 1.0430449655332195e-10)`.

Comment: `>>> integrate.dblquad(lambda theta1, theta2: (stats.beta.pdf(theta1, y1+1, n1-y1+1)*stats.beta.pdf(theta2, y2+1, n2-y2+1)), 0, 1, lambda x: x, lambda x: 1)
(0.7125928041119366, 1.0789513156470496e-10)
>>> integrate.dblquad(lambda theta1, theta2: (stats.beta.pdf(theta1, y1+1, n1-y1+1)*stats.beta.pdf(theta2, y2+1, n2-y2+1)*(theta2<theta1)), 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1)

(1.9163935683929993, 7.0961341247510745e-09)` 

Weird behaviour, I will try upgrading as I'm on version 0.16, but it is strange that there doesn't seem to be any issues raised on github for 0.16+ for this.